# What is the meaning of '有机结合‘ here?

Tags: meaning

The sentence before he said:

一般企业更多雇用的是员工的双手和双脚，而不是员工最有价值和创造力的部位--大脑。

I have this sentence:

面对这一业界难题，我们公司看到的不是两难，而是有机结合。
Next sentence:(this is from my fltrp text book, so I assume it is good 汉语）

我们在雇用员工双手的同时也雇用了员工的大脑，让员工不仅用手工作，而且用心用脑去工作。
How should I interpret '有机结合‘？

Comment: this is a dictionary question: organic combination， integration，also see http://baike.baidu.com/view/3470451.htm

Comment: An banal sentence, stop wasting time on this poor description.

Comment: Reechen, what do they want to integrate? Hand, leg and brain?? What does it mean in my sentence?? I really don't see what they are saying.

Comment: May we have the next sentence too?

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, "结合" means combination. "有机" in this sentence means the combinations goes vary well.

"有机" is a vary interesting words, it always means the change is not physical one, but a chemical one. It means something new is created by the combination, not just put them together.

Comment: physical/chemical ? organic/inorganic chemistry: 有机化学／无机化学

Comment: I think the logic goes like this: nowadays, people don't want chemicals in their food. 有机牛奶，有机蔬菜， 有机肉， 等等。These are considered 'good'. By association, 有机 has acquired a by-meaning of 'good'. Therefore, '不是两难，而是有机结合‘ means 'is not a dilemma, but a good combination'

Answer (score 0):

If there are two things that appear irrelevant or sometimes even opposite to each other, and you managed to couple or combine them with effort, and the coupling or combination produces beneficial effects, you may say you get "有机结合" of the two things.

We also use "有机结合" to describe a successful application of a technology in some certain field.

Comment: So what is being combined? The hands and the brain are, quite literally, 'organically linked'. You would write 'successfully linked' for ‘有机结合’？？

Answer (score 0):

有机 literally means organic.

English word "organic" have several meanings/usages. 有机 equals to (most of) them.

> 1 relating to or derived from living matter: organic soils.
>
> • Chemistry relating to or denoting compounds containing carbon (other than simple binary compounds and salts) and chiefly or ultimately of biological origin. Compare with inorganic.
>
> 2 (of food or farming methods) produced or involving production without the use of chemical fertilizers, pesticides, or other artificial chemicals. organic farming. organic meat.
>
> 3 Physiology relating to a bodily organ or organs.
>
> • Medicine (of a disease) affecting the structure of an organ.
>
> 4 denoting or characterized by a harmonious relationship between the elements of a whole: the organic unity of the integral work of art.
>
> • characterized by gradual or natural development: the organic growth of community projects.

I can't say for meaning (3), but 有机 is the same as organic in the rest three of organic's meanings.

The meaning of 有机 in the example in organic meaning 4.